# Distribution of the number of unique categories from a multinomial experiment

Tags: probability

Say we have a multinomial experiment where a $k$-sided dice is rolled $n$ times independently and $f=$ the number of unique dice sides. Does $f$ have a closed-form pmf (probability mass function)?  The [first answer under this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961442/distribution-of-number-of-unique-elements) gives an induction formula but I'm not sure how to write the closed-form probability.

If it's not easy to derive the pmf, any way one could approximate it? All I need is the expectation and variance of $f$. Getting E$(f)$ is straightforward as in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296005/the-expected-number-of-unique-elements-drawn-with-replacement), but I didn't figure out how to derive Var$(f)$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the die is weighted (unfair?), then that does enter into the pmf.  So you will need to add some notation to express how the sides are weighted.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! You are right. For now I only need the simplest case with a fair dice so I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an outline that I hope gives you a clear path to follow.

Adopting the notation from the last post you cited, let's write
$X= \sum I_j$  where $I_j$ is the indicator function of the event that position $j$ is occupied at least once. It is convenient to denote by $I_j'$ the indicator function of the complementary event that position $j$ is never chosen in any of the $n$ trials.

To compute the variance of $X$ you can start by expanding $Var(X)= E(X^2)- (E(X))^2$. Since you already know (from the post cited) how to compute $E(X)$, let's focus on computing the second moment $$E(X^2)= E( (\sum_j I_j)^2)= E( \sum_{j}  \sum_k I_j I_k)$$ The diagonal terms in this sum satisfy the algebraic identity $I_j I_j= I_j$   and the off-diagonal terms satisfy $I_j I_k = (1- I_j') (1- I_k') = 1- I_j'- I_k' + I_j' I_k'$. Apply linearity of expectation to evaluate the expectation of this sum.

The last term in this expansion is the indicator function of the event that neither position $j$ nor $k$ was ever occupied in any of the $n$ trials. The expectation of that event can be computed in a straightforward way by the same method as in that post. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296005/the-expected-number-of-unique-elements-drawn-with-replacement (The details vary depending on whether you wish to model the situation of all $k$ faces being equally likely or not.)

Comment: Ohhh that's clear. Thank you for the detailed answer!